# Getting certain data out of .txt file

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, external-files

I'd like to use an external .txt file to provide a table in my LaTeX document with data. To achieve this I've taken into consideration the pgfplotstable package and the filecontents package. Both of them enabled me to create a complete table out of the data (still, only after manually removing the [] brackets from my .txt file). But I would like to take only certain data and insert them into an existing table of my document.

The .txt file has [] brackets in it, that could be used as markers for a new entry line?

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable, filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
Title Data
[Name] Clarissa
[Family Name] Fray
[Age] 16
[Country] USA
[Gender] Female
[Haircolor] Red
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document} 

%% --------------------- What it should look like (but getting data from file)
\begin{figure}
    \rowcolors{1}{gray!25}{white}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\bfseries}l|X|} \hline
        Name & Clarissa \\ \hline
        Family Name & Fray \\ \hline
        Gender & Female \\ \hline
        Age & 16 \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{figure}

%%% --------------------- The best I can get (doesn't compile, because of
%%% the brackets in the .txt file and the space in [Family Name])
%\pgfplotstabletypeset[
%every head row/.style = {
%   before row = {
%       \hline
%       }
%   }, 
%after row = \hline,
%every even row/.style={
%   before row = {
%       \rowcolor[gray]{0.9}
%       }
%},
%columns/Title/.style = {column type=|l, column name=First},
%columns/Data/.style = {column type=|l|, column name=Second},
%col sep = space,
%string type,
%]{data.txt}

\end{document}
```

Any help is really appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You could preprocess the file with a tool like `sed`: `sed -r 's/\[//g;s/\]/ \&/g;s/(.*)/\1 \\\\/g' data.txt` strips the brackets, inserts an `&` between the would-be columns` and finishes with each line with a `\\ `. Each of these steps is demarcated by a `;` (e.g., `s/(.*)/\1 \\\\/g` adds the `\\ `), so you can not do one of these things by cutting out that part of the command.

Comment: I think @jon is right, using regular expressions to conform your text file to what pgfplots expects is easier than the other way around.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! As I have not used this before, do you know if it is a solution for Windows users as well?

Comment: I have't used a Windows computer (where I had the permission to install anything) in many years, but it seems like there are many options available: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127318/is-there-any-sed-like-utility-for-cmd-exe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a normal Windows 10 PC, the following should work from a PowerShell prompt. It may also work on Windows 7 or 8, but I can't test that easily right now:

```
cat .\data.txt | select -skip 1 | % { $_ -replace "\[", "" } | % { $_ -replace "\]", "," } | Out-File -encoding ascii data2.txt
```

Annotated version:

- `cat .\data.txt` gets all the content of data.txt and sends it to the next command in the pipeline
- `| select -skip 1` skips the first line (your headers) from the piped input
- `| % { $_ -replace "[", "" }` replaces open bracket characters with empty strings
- `% { $_ -replace "]", "," }` replaces close bracket characters with commas
- `| Out-File -encoding ascii data2.txt` writes the pipeline data into a file data2.txt in plan ASCII format

This yields a file data2.txt containing:

```
Name, Clarissa
Family Name, Fray
Age, 16
Country, USA
Gender, Female
Haircolor, Red
```

and with a document of:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document} 

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
every head row/.style = {
   before row = {
       \hline
       }
   }, 
after row = \hline,
every even row/.style={
   before row = {
       \rowcolor[gray]{0.9}
       },
},
columns/Title/.style = {column type=|l, column name=First},
columns/Data/.style = {column type=|l|, column name=Second},
col sep = comma,
string type,
]{data2.txt}

\end{document}
```

you get output of:

[image]